# Openbravo - Connecting pgadmin with postgresql database in Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin, openbravo

I have installed Openbravo ERP 3.0 in Ubuntu 12.04(LTS). After completed the installation I tried to connect with postgresql database using pgadmin 9.1. I gave all the details as mentioned in this link: http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Appliance/Openbravo.

Also I have changed the config file settings like listen_addresses="*". I got this error after I click "Ok" button

[image]

Could anyone give suggestion to fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to connect via psql?

Comment: I tried.. But got this... Error: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.

Comment: The errors you get from psql and pgAdmin are probably because of different reasons. Please check the entries in pg_hba.conf on the server. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication-problems.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem comes because of not mentioning the local cluster or data area for PostgreSQL. To do this after installing Openbravo, need to give this command in terminal

> psql -d openbravo -U tad -h localhost -p 5932

Finally give the PostgreSQL configuration details as mentioned in this [link](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Ubuntu:_advanced_topics.)

It works fine now...

Answer (score 0):

1. To be able to reach the server remotely you have to add the following line into the file: /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf:

listen_addresses = '*'

2. PostgreSQL, by default, refuses all connections it receives from any remote address. You have to relax these rules by adding this line to /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf:

host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

This is an access control rule that lets anyone login from any address if a valid password is provided (the md5 keyword). You can use your network/mask instead of 0.0.0.0/0 to only allow access from certain IP addresses.

3. When you have applied these modifications to your configuration files, you will need to restart the PostgreSQL server.

/etc/init.d/postgresql start

Now, you will be able to login to your server remotely